# How can I change the start theme color of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

I know that I can customize the styles as per the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color). I want to change the part that has the vscode logo.

However, I have not been able to change this view (the one you get if you close all editor tabs / welcome page) in any way.

[image: vscode start window screenshot]

I tried all the configurations in the attached documentation, however, none of them worked.

Comment: what part of your screenshot do you want to change exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It's just `editor.background`. Ex.

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.background": "#ffffff" // TODO choose a colour
    // haha I used white to burn off your eyeballs
}
```

Note that this colour customization point applies to... well the (entire) editor.

Comment: I did know that, ty. but my problem is that I can't change the color of what appears in the screenshot

Answer (score -1):

To change the theme color of VSCode, you need to:

1. Open VSCode
2. Press "Ctrl+Shift+P" on Windows or "Cmd+Shift+P" on Mac to open the Command Palette.
3. Type "Open User Settings (JSON)" in the Command Palette and select it.
   It will reflect all visual studio code windows. If you want a specific project or workspace customization Type the "Open Workspace Settings (JSON)" option only shows if you have a workspace (Project)
4. Add the following JSON code to the settings.json(Open User Settings (JSON)) file:

   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
   "button.background": "your_color_code_here",
   "activityBar.background": "your_color_code_here",
   "dropdown.background":"your_color_code_here",
   }

Replace "your_color_code_here" with the hexadecimal code of the color you want to set as the theme color. You can use any online color picker to get the hexadecimal code of your desired color.

[image: Open User Settings (JSON) settings.json]

(OR)

If you want only the workspace or project Add the following JSON code to the settings.json(Open Workspace Settings (JSON)) file

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
   "button.background": "your_color_code_here",
    "activityBar.background": "your_color_code_here",
    "dropdown.background":"your_color_code_here",
```

}

Replace "your_color_code_here" with the hexadecimal code of the color you want to set as the theme color. You can use any online color picker to get the hexadecimal code of your desired color.

[image: Open Workspace Settings (JSON) settings.json]

5. Save the settings.json file

Once you have followed these steps, the theme color of the VSCode should be changed to the color you specified in the settings.json file.

[image: VS Code Color Customization]

Comment: Thanks for the steps, but my problem is finding the specific setting that changes the background of the screenshot

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).